# How can I hide some elements in my products.html page when I click on a button in my index.html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, hide

I know to hide an element in the same page I have to do this:

```
 $('#district-collection').click(function(){ 
       $('.hemisphere').hide();

 });
```

My problem is `.hemisphere` is in my `products.html` page and `index.html` doesn't see it!

Comment: you need a place to store the class of the element you want to hide and retrieve that class when that page is loaded and hide that element. try using local storage.

Comment: how products.html page is rendered? how navigation happens?

Comment: Does your handler work if you add `console.log` to function? Maybe you need to wait until your page will load and set it on `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: 1. put ```console.log('something')``` anywhere in the function to see that is triggered. if it is not triggered, see if you selector actually works; 2 test "hemisphere" could be selected at all in js

Comment: @JRodDynamite jsfiddle is not very suitable for demonstrating navigation between different html pages.

Comment: @MrLister : Oh okay. My bad. Didn't read the question properly. Thanks for pointing out! :)

Comment: @JRodDynamite It would be handy to have something like that though.

Comment: @Payam Assuming that your button on index.html submits to myproducts.html, you can give myproducts' `body` an id, say, `nohemisphere`, and then use `myproducts.html#nohemisphere` to submit to, and put `#nohemisphere:target hemisphere {display:none}` in the CSS. The solution will need to be persistent though, won't it?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. @Mr Lister your answer makes sense I will give it a try! To be more clear on my situation I am going to have in my index.html,  10 category of products. Each of these categories will have minimum of 10 products in them. I want to use only one page (products.html) and put all the 100 products in that page but when users click on each of these categories on index.html, it only shows the 10 related products to that category in products.html.